# Amazon Lex V2 Lambda python code to get intent name or any response back from lambda is not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

'''
Trying to get response back as name of the intent from lambda for Amazon Lex v2. It can be string or any response back in simple program.

I have referred the V2 Lex documentation but I can come-up with below code which shows error after several attempts. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html

error : "Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled"

'''

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  entity = event["currentIntent"]["slots"]["Nm"].title()
  intent = event["currentIntent"]["name"]


  response = {
    'sessionState': {
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close'
        },
        'state': 'Fulfilled'
    },
    'messages': [
          'contentType': 'PlainText',
          'content': "The intent you are in now is "+intent+"!"
        ],
    
    }    

  return response
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'messages' field is an array of objects, not an array of strings. It should be declared as follows:

```
'messages': [
          {
              'contentType': 'PlainText',
              'content': "The intent you are in now is "+intent+"!"
            }
        ]
```

---

Reference:

[Amazon Lex - Lambda Response format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html#lambda-response-format)

Comment: Hello, @OmarRosadio Thanks for your time and effort. Yes, I have tried your suggestion, but the same error is still there. Am I missing another thing?

Comment: Please update the question with the new code and an sample request

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The solution that worked for me is like below

```
var response = {};
    response.messages = [
        message
    ];
    response.sessionState = {
        sessionAttributes:sessionAttributes,
        intent : {
            name : intentRequest.interpretations[0].intent.name,
            state : 'Fulfilled'
        },
        dialogAction: {   
            type: "Close",   
            fulfillmentState: "Fulfilled"
        }
    };
```

Refer to lex v2 developer guide page 69 Response format
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lex2.0.pdf